# Switching between ethernet interfaces on Ubuntu 10.04 server

Tags: server

I have Ubuntu 10.04 "SERVER" installed on a system with two ethernet ports. I use only one at a time. I wanted to know if I can switch between ports without using ifup and ifdown every time. That means when I connect my LAN cable on eth0 it should work and it does. But when I disconnect the LAN cable and connect it on eth1 I have to ifdown eth0 and only then it works.

In my /etc/network/interfaces file I have configured both eth0 and eth1. there is no problem other than I have to switch it manually with ifdown and ifup every time.

Comment: Are you connecting both to the same switch? It should work if you have assigned static ips for both interfaces. It will also work if have set a dhcp client to obtain ips. Can you add your interfaces file contents to your question?

Comment: There is only one lan cable coming from switch. I connect it to one ethernet port, then I disconnect it from there and connect it to other ehternet port. but when I do this I have to ifdown first ethernet port eth0 only then the network ping will be available. It is not about dhcp or static IP.

Comment: You can configure a script in `/etc/network/if-post-down.d/` folder (it exists in ubuntu 11.10 at least). I think these scripts are executed after ("post") a device is disconnected. I don't know the exact details for such a script, nor if it works in 10.04, hence I posted this as a comment.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)

Answer (score 3):

mediageek posted this as a comment. This may essentially be the answer, and it's the best we've got (so far), so here it is:

> You can configure a script in `/etc/network/if-post-down.d/` folder
>   (it exists in ubuntu 11.10 at least). I think these scripts are
>   executed after ("post") a device is disconnected. I don't know the
>   exact details for such a script, nor if it works in 10.04, hence I
>   posted this as a comment.

– [medigeek](/users/5538/medigeek) [Apr 12 '12 at 8:57](https://askubuntu.com/questions/121256/switching-between-ethernet-interfaces-on-ubuntu-10-04-server#comment144366_121256)

To complete that, I believe it may be sufficient to do this:

1. Create a script called `start-eth1` in `/etc/network/if-post-down.d` directory by running:

   ```
   cd /etc/network/if-post-down.d
   gksu gedit start-eth1
   ```
2. Give it these contents in the text editor (then save the file and quit the text editor):

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   [ "$IFACE" = eth0 ] && ifup eth1
   ```

   I believe that will check to see if the interface being disconnected is `eth0`, and if it is, then it will start `eth1`.
3. Make the script executable so it will be run:

   ```
   sudo chmod +x start-eth1
   ```

Please understand that *I'm not sure how well this will work (or even if it will work)*.

<sup>If anyone has more information about this please feel free to edit this to improve it, and/or post a new answer.</sup>